# CSS Printing Properties using Textarea

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have to print several textarea elements in my code. Here is an example of one:

```css
@media screen {
textarea[division]{
        font-size: 13px;
        height: 70px;
        resize: none;
        text-align: center;
    }
  
  textarea[top]{
        float: right;
        width: 150px;   
    }
 }
  
 @media print {
 
 textarea {
            margin:0; 
            padding:0; 
            border:none; 
            display:flex;
            overflow: hidden;
        } 
 textarea[division]{
            overflow: hidden;
            border: none;
            margin:0; 
            padding:0; 
            margin-bottom: 0;
            white-space: nowrap;
            resize: none;
            display:block;
            font-size: 13px;
        } 
    button{
            visibility: hidden;
        }
}
```

```html
<div><p><b><br>Division:</b><textarea id='transfer_out_division' type='text' placeholder="EMD - AFC Program & Information Management" top required division></textarea></p></div>

  
<button type="button" onclick="window.print();return false;"/>EXPORT PDF</button>
```

I would like the text to be printed on the same line as Division and push the text to the next line once it runs out of space. How would I fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I correct the HTML part, because there were some `<br>` tags, and it does not work very well with CSS placement. I add the `.container` class too, in order to use flex-box.

```
<p class="container">
    <b>Division:</b>
    <textarea id='transfer_out_division' type='text'
        placeholder="EMD - AFC Program & Information Management" top required division></textarea>
</p>
```

And the CSS part:

```
@media print {
    textarea {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        border: none;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    textarea[division] {
        overflow: hidden;
        border: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        white-space: nowrap;
        resize: none;
        font-size: 13px;
    }

    button {
        visibility: hidden;
    }

    .container {
        display: flex;
    } 
}
```

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I was looking for, how would I go about pushing a word to the next line if it goes past the container?

Comment: Because it is still being cut off when I go to print

Comment: Yeah @HopeDunner I tried many combinaisons and still not working, and I cannot longuer work on it, I'm sorry :/

Comment: you got me pretty far with containers trick, thank you!